# libcurl multi interface single easy interface multiple requests

Tags: c++, http, curl, httpclient, libcurl

I am looking to use libcurl for asynchronous HTTP requests. For that I am using multi interface provided by libcurl. My application will be having many requests coming periodically for which I am looking to use single easy interface and add it to the multi interface. I am not planning to use new easy interface handles for each and every http requests because it opens up a new connection with a new session. I need to make all requests in a single connection/session. So, I am looking to use single easy interface handle for all requests.

With this model, I am getting issues in making multiple http requests. The first request goes through using curl_multi_perform with no issue. Response is processed. The second request does not go through with curl_multi_perform. When curl_multi_perform is called second time, the second parameter running_handles is returned as 0 and not 1.

This is the flow of APIs I am using at high level.

```
curl_easy_init()
curl_multi_init()
curl_multi_add_handle()
curl_multi_perform() // running_handles returned is 1.
//look for response (curl_multi_timeout, curl_multi_fdset, select, curl_multi_info_read, ...)

curl_multi_perform() // This does not work and running_handles returned is 0
...
curl_multi_cleanup()
curl_easy_cleanup()
```

Can't libcurl multi interface be used with single easy interface added for multiple requests coming over a period of time?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

When an easy handle has completed its transfer and you want to re-use that same handle for a subsequent transfer, you need to first remove it from the multi handle ([curl_multi_remove_handle](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_remove_handle.html)) and (possible set new options and then) re-add it with [curl_multi_add_handle](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_add_handle.html) to make it start another transfer.

But note that when using the multi interface, the connection pool and reuse mechanism is owned by the multi handle and the easy handle so connections can and will be re-used across easy handles as long as you keep the multi handle alive.